# Confused With File Permissions On Samba Network

Tags: samba

I've installed Samba and trying to share a mount point on my server to the rest of the network so that any file I put inside the share has rwx access provided to everyone. In the /etc/samba/smb.conf file I have added the lines below at the bottom of the file.

```
[RAID-ARRAY]
    comment = RAID_DISKS
    path = /mnt/raiddrives
    writeable = yes
    browsable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    read only = no
    create mask = 0777
```

I have also just put some chmod commands on a text file I have just created inside of /mnt/raiddrives.

```
chmod a+rwx test.txt
```

So why, when I access the text file from a computer on the network and try to change it does it give me a permissions error?

Comment: Did you try to restart the Samba services after changing the mask from 0775? `sudo service smbd restart` and `sudo service nmbd restart`

Comment: Yes I have. I will reboot the machine now to make sure

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out just now. Wow I can't believe I honestly didn't scroll down enough in gedit. There was 1 more line underneath saying

```
read only = yes
```